# How to properly set the type for property `d` in `path` element in a d3 react typescript application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw a triangle using the d3 `symbol()` method and assigned it to a variable `symbolTri`.

```
import { symbol, symbolTriangle } from "d3"
const symbolTri = symbol().size(100).type(symbolTriangle)

export const Component = () => {
    // ...
    return (
        <g>
            <path d={symbolTri()} />
        </g>
    )
}
```

But while setting the `d` property a typescript error `Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.` occurred. And while hovering over the error it shows `'d' value should be of type d?: string | undefined;`. But I'm unable to set it properly. Any help, or suggestion would be really helpful.

Comment: Why are you calling `symbolTri()`? Is it a function?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen The d3 docs page says d3.symbol() `Constructs a new symbol generator of the specified type and size.` https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution, assuming that the output of `symbolTri()` cannot be null (which seems a reasonable assumption in this case), is to use the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator), which effectively tells the TypeScript compiler that this variable will never be `null`:

```
<path d={symbolTri()!} />
```